# Express.js next like functionality using a generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a list of functions `functions`. Each of these functions take `x`(irrelevant) and `next` as arguments. I'm trying to implement something like a `middleware` as present in `express.js`. Each of the middlewares run and pass contol to the next `middleware` by calling `next`.

```
    let x;
    function* generator (functions, next) => {
       for (let _function of functions){
         yield _function(x,next);
       }
    }
    function next(generator){
      generator.next();
    }
    //cant quite decide on how to write the below lines
    //I can't bind the generator to next because it is not yet defined
    //
    generator(functions1, next.bind('???'));
    generator(functions2, next);
    generator(functions3, next);
```

`functions{1,2,3}` are a list of middlewares.
Each of the functions in the middleware would look like

```
f(x, next){
   //do things with x
   next();
   //maybe do more things
}
```

This is something I tried entirely on my own. I'm wondering if there is an altogether better way of doing this. I'm looking for plain js implementations without using libraries.

Comment: So, you want `next()` to call the next function in the `functions` array?

Comment: There's really no good reason to use generators here unless I'm missing something.

Comment: How are these three calls to `generator`, and the three function arrays `functions1`, `functions2` and `functions3` related?

Comment: 1) Yes , next should call the next function in the function array.

2) Yes , I could do it without a generator. But I wanted to keep the syntax similar to `express` by using `next` function without any arguments.(On second thought I think i can do it by binding variables to `next`, but I have a gut feeling that express also does it via `generators`).

3)There are no relations. Those lines were added to state that there could be multiple function pipelines independent of one another.

Comment: The ultimate intent is to keep adding the functions to middleware by only passing `next` function as a way of passing control to the next function in queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
function* generate(functions, next) => {
  for (const fn of functions){
    yield fn(x, next);
  }
}
function run(functions) {
  const generator = generate(function next() {
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// pass a closure over the `generator` instance here
    generator.next();
  });
}
```

Of course this does not yet allow any value-passing between the functions.
And `run` would be so much easier to implement without generator functions, but I'll assume you're doing this as a learning exercise.

Comment: My intution was, the function `next` should keep state. I'm curious to see an implementation without generator because you said it would be easier.

Comment: Well `function run(functions) { var i=0; function next() { (0, functions[i++])(x, next); } next(); }` might be one way. You could even do it without state, passing different callbacks to the middlewares.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks .